# Why I get different values for boxShadow in browsers?

Tags: javascript, css, return-value, box-shadow

I need to manipulate the `boxShadow` dynamically however I get different values depending on the browser.
How do I fix it?

Example:

```
var shadow = document.getElementById("demo").style.boxShadow;
```

**In google chrome**: `box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 150px 0px inset;`

**In mozilla**: `box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 150px 0px inset;`

But at the **edge** I get rgb and inset on different position: `box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 150px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)`

I have not tried it on safari

Is there any way to solve this? I need the code boxShadow in all browsers to be the same.

Comment: Can't test, but what about `getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("demo")).boxShadow;`? Getting the style property is bound to discrepancy. Also, one workaround would be to store it somewhere it won't move, like a `data-shadow="..."`

Comment: Agreed, saving the shadow to a data attribute would be the best course of action, because in my experience browsers tend to return different CSS values depending on the one you're using. Read about data attributes here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: It might be a *slight* complication, but you can also just write a parser for this. The syntax is fairly simple, so you can read it, re-formatted into what you expect, then assign it back. The browser seems to accept the inline style attribute having the values in any sequence (e.g, `inset` is in the beginning or the end). So, for the browser it doesn't seem to matter how you write it - it will read and understand it.

Comment: Ok, chrome and mozilla show same code but any idea how to turn "mirror" code im edge? .., to look same as in chrome, mozilla ...